# Shell script to remove quotes when using SED

Tags: bash, sed, variables

I'm trying to change a line of syntax in a config file where the line looks like the following:

```
host="192.0.2.100"
```

I'm writing a script that would require input the user to change the ip and keep the same format as above. What I wrote:

```
#/bin/bash
echo "enter IP"
read inputIP
sed -i /host=/c\host="$inputIP" /path/file.xml
```

What I get when i run this in file is:

```
host=192.0.2.100
```

So the question is how do I run this and not lose the quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Quotes are special for the shell, it removes them in a so called "quote removal" before sending the paramteres to sed. To keep them, escape them by backslashes:

```
sed -i /host=/c\host=\"$inputIP\" /path/file.xml
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! That did the trick!

Comment: Peter, please select this as the accepted answer.